# Android Audio Loopback

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm a deaf person so I'm using 'Live Transcribe' (by Google) a lot, the problem is that it cannot capture the internal audio in Android (so phone calls or any internal audio will be translated too), sadly it can only capture external sounds.

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10 Plus.

I was looking for an audio loopback driver for android but could not find one, I thought I'd give it a try and make my own app if there's no such app (I'm a software developer).

Is this even possible? what would you suggest?

Comment: I use OpenSL ES to capture audio from the mic and process it. I think this would be an interesting and valuable app. Good luck.

Comment: why you are taging python, C#?

Comment: Do not spam tags.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but you could try to hack a headphone jack into a loopback plug.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a solution for your problem and fortunately I came across a recent API in android 10 which is AudioPlaybackCapture API that lets you record internal sounds and perhaps you can find a way to process that audio and convert it to text too!!

The android developer website says and I quote:  "The primary use case is for streaming apps that want to capture the audio being played by games."

You can read more about the API here: [AudioPlaybackCapture API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture)